# automatically change div or div's content javascript

Tags: javascript

i want a script that change automatically my entire div or content of div. Please, just javascript, note jQuery.

I tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var kickoff = new Date("May 10, 2015 23:18:00"),
timerContainer = document.getElementById('timerContent'),
timer; // Added for visibility in the global scope.

function cdtd() {

 var now = new Date(),
  timeDiff = kickoff.getTime() - now.getTime();

if (timeDiff <= 0) {

 clearTimeout(timer);
 timerContainer.innerHTML = '<div>KICK OFF!!!!</div> <img src="img1.gif" />';

} else {

// This style of declaration is just preference.
var seconds = Math.floor(timeDiff / 1000),
    minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60),
    hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60),
    days = Math.floor(hours / 24);

if (seconds < 10) seconds = "0" + seconds;
if (minutes < 10) minutes = "0" + minutes;
if (hours < 10) hours = "0" + hours;
if (days < 10) days = "0" + days;

// Using an array simplifies the process of creating the text
// In some browsers this is more performant than using '' + ''
// In other browsers it's not, in reality the difference marginal in
// small iterations like this one.
var textTemplateArray = [
      days, 'Days',
      minutes, 'Minutes',
      hours, 'Hours',
      seconds, 'Seconds'
    ];

timerContainer.innerHTML = textTemplateArray.join(' ');
     }
}

timer = setInterval(cdtd, 1000);
```

And i don't know how to write in `<body>` element for the code work. I want to put a div that change after few second with another div, and so on... with 3-4 divs.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "change my div"? Change in what way?

Answer (score 0):

I think I am right in assuming that you want javascript to change the text in a `<div>` element to the value of a certain variable and to repeat this every second/any time frame to update the value shown.

That can be done like this:

```
setInterval(function(){document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = 'New text'},1000);
```

which will repeat the following every second(1000 milliseconds):

```
document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = 'New text'
```

where `'newtext'` should be replaced by the variable name